# How To Build d3.js From Source?

Tags: d3.js

How are the files "d3.js" and "d3.min.js" produced from the many source files in the d3 github repository, and what tools are required to build them?

I see a package.json file which suggests that npm is involved, and also a Makefile -- I'm not sure what program uses that.

1. What tools do I need to build the files?
2. What commands do I issue to those tools?

Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript is an interpreted language, therefore, you need not compile it. Furthermore, the interpreter of this language is the browser itself, so you don't need any additional software to use it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this misses the point of my post entirely.  I am aware js is an interpreted langauge.  Javascript applications are still "built" (not compiled) using tools like "grunt" these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is that d3 uses SMASH:

https://github.com/mbostock/smash/wiki